# Ruby differences between print formatting

Tags: ruby

I am starting to learn Ruby and I am using `print` and I saw that it can use two string formatting:

1. `print "#{var}"`
2. `print "%r %d %r" % [var1,var2,var3]`

Of course one difference is that in the first one you don't need to put the type of parameter you are passing, but what I really want to know is which one of this would work better for Ruby and some other tips that you could give me.

Thanks.

Comment: The first is not formatting, it's interpolating a variable into a string, which, in your example is a waste of CPU cycles because `print var` would accomplish the same thing, only faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most people use the former method as it automatically calls the `.to_s` method of the object to display the value.  You can use this to your advantage by overriding the class's `.to_s` method to make it display whatever you wish.

Frankly I've never seen the second method used in any code I've looked at.

Comment: The second method, which is classic C `printf` style, is useful when working with numbers, where `%d` or `%.1f` are often used to render floating point values in a concise, readable format.

Comment: The "printf" or "sprintf" format is extremely useful for any formatted output, columnar reports. I use it often when I output numbered results.

Comment: I encountered the second method in https://github.com/stympy/faker/blob/master/lib/faker/company.rb#L24 It is used to add leading zeros.